# Как правильно отправить данные на чистом javascript ajax ?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Добрый день! Пытаюсь освоить ajax без всяких jquery, т.е. чистый ajax работа с объектом XMLHttpRequest и т.п. Пытаюсь отослать данные вот таким образом

```
//Кроссбраузерное создание Ajax объекта
function getXmlHttp(){
      var xmlhttp;
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
      if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    }

//Добавляем товар в корзину
function productAddToBasket(Action,ProductID,Quantity,AjaxBasket)
    {
        var CurrPagePath = window.location.pathname;    //Текущая страница
        var AjaxObject = getXmlHttp();  //Получаем объект XMLHttpRequest

        //Настройка обработчика
        AjaxObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                alert("Товар добавлен в корзину!");
            }

        //Открываем соединение
        AjaxObject.open('POST', CurrPagePath, true);

        //Отправляем данные
        var Data = "action="+Action+"&id="+ProductID+"&quantity="+Quantity+"&ajax_basket="+AjaxBasket+"";
        AjaxObject.send(Data);
    }
```

Вызов функции productAddToBasket осуществляю вот так (это в теле шаблона):

```
 <span onClick="productAddToBasket('ADD2BASKET',<?=$Item['ID']; ?>,1,'Y')" >
      Купить
</span>
```

Данные та уходят но вот так http://joxi.ru/SsrTU4wyTJCsLtlN7d8 т.е. как одна строка, а хотелось быть вот так http://joxi.ru/ccrTU_3JTJAtGic2x9c т.е. **Параметр->Значение**. Вот я и не пойму как мне сформировать переменную Data которую я посылаю тут   AjaxObject.send(Data); чтобы данные ушли правильно? Да и ещё момент, функция productAddToBasket() после вызова через onClick не останавливается, а надо было бы чтобы она отрабатывала правильно, 1 клик - 1 вызов.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а вы не путаете POST c GET-ом?

Comment: А в чём причина неиспользования jQuery? Тут явно не саморазвитие, а конкретная задача. Не лучше ли её сделать инструментами которые легко поддерживать, а не велосипедостроением заниматься?

Comment: @dimka3210, судя по коду - человеку еще многое нужно покурить перед тем как "иметь полное право" использовать что-то типа jQuery, хотя - да, согласен, если это "рабочая задача" - решать ее таким способом неоправданно глупо.

По поводу непосредственно кода -  на вскидку, как минимум, отсутствует хедер (xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");)

Comment: @AlexWindHope да какой смысл, вот вы на калькуляторе бк программировали ? в смысле придумывали программы и кодили их ? как вам утверждение, что пользоваться полнотекстовым экраном всем кто не прогал пару лет на калькуляторе ещё рано ? Если нормально подходить к вопросу то и jquery и др библиотеки как раз приучают к правильным решениям. Пара лет вот такого быдлокодинга на "чистом" js и мы получим очередное чудовище с совершенно невообразимыми паттернами в голове. А пара лет с фреймворком дает  понимание не только как его юзать, но и как он работает.

Comment: @eicto - у меня нет желания с Вами спорить в этом вопросе. И, если что - я не считаю что такие вещи как ajax нужно обязательно щупать своими руками, тем не менее я убеждет в том, что это было-бы, по меньшей мере - полезно. Но, в общем случае - достаточно просто один раз внимательно прочитать и понять че к чему, не более того.

А вот насчет "дает понимание" - тоже, скажем так, как минимум не всегда правда (я о "jQuery программистах"). Хотя да, отчасти и вы правы, но речь была немного не об этом

Comment: На самом деле я пару лет успешно использую jquery но хочу освоить именно чистый javascript чтобы можно было писать приложения (в основном всякие плюшки для сайтов) не зависимые от сторонней библиотеки типа jquery или mootools и пр.

Comment: @maler1988, я где-то читал хорошую статью, где автор высказывал свое мнение на счет того, что в jQuery нет ничего плохого. Также он писал, что хороший программист должен работать в первую очередь эффективно, а jQuery - это как раз про скорость разработки, эффективность и обратную совместимость ценой 60 килобайт кода. Даже если вы станете специалистом среднего звена, то все равно едва ли когда-нибудь будете использовать голый XHR. К тому времени вы, возможно, на JS-фреймворки перейдете, где также используются свои встроенные HTTP-клиенты, а не голый XHR.

Answer (score 1):

а вы делайте разбор параметров

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

С jQuery и прочими библиотеками совсем забыли как выглядит чистый код. Зачем грузить излишние километры бесполезного кода библиотеки, когда можно обойтись десятком строк простого кода.

Вот Код: (не пинайте больно, написал буквально за не сколько минут)

это типовая функция

```
      /* Данная функция создаёт кроссбраузерный объект XMLHTTP */   
function getXmlHttp(){
   var xmlhttp;
   try {
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
   catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
       catch (E) {
         xmlhttp = false;
       }
    }
   if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
 return xmlhttp;
}
```

А это сама функция которая отсылает POST на сервер

```
function sendingForm (formname) {
  var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); // Создаём объект XMLHTTP
          var p = 'ajax=1';
    for(var i=0;i<document.forms[formname].elements.length;i++){ 
     p += "&"+document.forms[formname].elements[i].name+"="+encodeURIComponent(document.forms[formname].elements[i].value) ;//присваиваем значение 
          }
 alert( p ) ; // проверяем что отправляем

  xmlhttp.open('POST', 'ajax/', true); // Открываем асинхронное соединение
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Отправляем кодировку
  xmlhttp.send(p); // Отправляем POST-запрос
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Ждём ответа от сервера
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Ответ пришёл
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Сервер вернул код 200 
        alert( 'Ответ получен, Значит данные отправлены успешно !' ) ; // проверяем что отправляем
       /*
        Место для кода обработчика событий
       */
       }
      }
    } ;
 }
```

Вот собственно эту форму мы и отправляем:

```
<form name="panelcontent" method="POST" id="panelcontent">
   <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" />
   <input type="text" id="id1" name="name2" />
  <div class="fieldInput">
  <button type="button" class="blue-pill" id="panelContentButton" onClick="sendingForm ('panelcontent')">Сохранить</button>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Как-то так, файл для js желательно сохранять в кодировке UTF-8

Comment: о каком чистом коде идет речь ? что такое по вашему `document.getElementByClassName()` ? Точнее сколько тут символов is спецификации js ? А спецификация w3c на самом деле описывает интерфейсы к браузеру, не обязательно javascript.

Comment: Ну DOM-метод это не внешняя библиотека в конце концов, да и собственно я ответил по существу на заданный вопрос.

Comment: DOM это внешняя библиотека относительно js, если например jQuery реализовать нативно, вы сразу поменяете свое мнение ? (минус убрал, т.к. тут хотя-бы ответ теперь есть)

Comment: Ага спасибо! Буду пробовать.